# How to use std::find to search in a <vector>?

Tags: c++, vector, std

I have this Map:

```
Map<Id,shared_ptr<Fan>> fans;
```

inside `Fan` I have this vector:

```
vector<Id> friendsIds;
```

I wanna search for a specific Id inside this vector so I use:

```
vector<Id>::iterator idsIterator;

vector<Id>::iterator first=fans[fanId]->friendsIds.begin();

vector<Id>::iterator last=fans[fanId]->friendsIds.end();

idsIterator=std::find(first, last, friendId);
```

but I get this huge error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - no matching function for call to 'find(std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator&, std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator&, int)'
    - '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int> >' is not derived from 
     'std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT2, std::char_traits<_CharT> >'
    - candidate is:
    - Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<11 74 0 __value 14 std::__is_char 1 #074 0 __value 14 
     std::__is_char 1 #0,std::istreambuf_iterator<#0,std::char_traits<#0>>>::__type 
     find(std::istreambuf_iterator<#0,std::char_traits<#0>>, std::istreambuf_iterator<#0,std::char_traits<#0>>, const #0 &) '
```

Comment: Do you have `#include <algorithm>`?

Comment: @user3036061: its where std::find lives

Comment: it is the header file where std::find should be. if you use it, include algorithm

Comment: Like you (must) have `#include <vector>` to be able to use `std::vector`, the same way you need `#include <algorithm>` to be able to use `std::find`.

Comment: it gives me this error on the include:
Multiple markers at this line
 - fatal error: altorightm: No such file or 
  directory

Comment: @user3036061: That's because it's spelt `<algorithm>`.

Comment: altorightm -> algorithm

Comment: @user3036061 - sorry, I made a typo in my comment, which I edited a bit later. It must be `#include <algorithm>`.

Comment: thnx alot !!! it works

Comment: @user3036061 - glad that it worked. I posted an answer, the same as my comment, which helped you.

Comment: Why on earth did this receive a downvote?

Answer (score 8):

You need to have

```
#include <algorithm>
```

in your program.

The same way you need `#include <vector>` to use `std::vector`, you need `#include <algorithm>` to use `std::find`.

Comment: this is indeed the answer. but the next question is: WTF is that error all about? and _could_ is possibly be any less helpful if it tried?